# Isn't the http module of nodejs capable of receiving / sending the whole request / response at once?

Tags: node.js, http, nodejs-stream

I am learning to `http` module of `nodejs`. I found a section in the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http) that says:

> The interface is careful to never buffer entire requests or responses

Does it means that this module is not capable of receiving / sending the whole request / response at once and it receives / sends in chunks instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it means that this module is not capable of receiving / sending the whole request / response at once and it receives / sends in chunks instead?

That's correct: `http` is based on streams, just like the underlying `net` module.

There are plenty of modules available to abstract these streams away for you, and do offer receiving the response in its entirity (in memory, so be careful with large responses). For example, [`request`](https://github.com/request/request) and [`http.min`](https://github.com/matjaz/node-http.min).